# SSL certificate authentication error for On-Premise Microsoft Dynamics CRM on Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, dynamics-crm

I am working on Microsoft Dynamics CRM API through which I perform actions on Dynamics CRM. I have completed API authentication for Online versions of Dynamics CRM but the same PHP code generates SSL authentication Error with On-Premise Dynamics CRM.
I also added SSL certificate following this [**Install SSL**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2013/12/09/creating-ssl-certificates-for-crm-test-environment.aspx) link.

**More clearly**

I want to authenticate On-Premise Dynamics CRM using PHP API from another computer.

I installed SSL certificate but the error remain same for API authentication.

On-Premise Dynamics CRM is always accessible with HTTP/HTTPS protocol from any browser.

Any Guideline, Support and help.

Thanks.